# Selenium Cookie to Curl Cookie

Tags: php, python, selenium, curl, cookies

How to convert a cookie saved by selenium  (`driver.get_cookies()`) to a cookie that can be used with `curl` ?

The content o selenium cookie when dumped to a text file looks like this:

```
[{u'domain': u'.site.com', u'name': u'NID', u'value': u'somelooooooooooongvalue', u'expiry': 1443722412, u'path': u'/', u'secure': False}, {u'domain': u'.site.com', u'name': u'SID', u'value': u'somelooooooooooooooongvalue', u'expiry': 1490983212, u'path': u'/', u'secure': False}]
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Is `curl` a requirement or `selenium` to `requests` cookie transfer would also work for you?

Comment: @alecxe Yes, curl is a requirement, I need to use the cookie dumped from selenium in a curl request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve this with a regex.

Example cookies dumped from `selenium` with `driver.get_cookies()`:

```
$seleniumCookies = "[{u'domain': u'.site.com', u'name': u'NID', u'value': u'somelooooooooooongvalue', u'expiry': 1443722412, u'path': u'/', u'secure': False}, {u'domain': u'.site.com', u'name': u'SID', u'value': u'somelooooooooooooooongvalue', u'expiry': 1490983212, u'path': u'/', u'secure': False}]";

$curlCookies = "";

preg_match_all('/\'name\': u\'(.*?)\', u\'value\': u\'(.*?)\'/i', $seleniumCookies, $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
for ($i = 0; $i < count($matches[0]); $i++) {
    $name =  $matches[1][$i];
    $value =  $matches[2][$i];

    $curlCookies .= "$name=$value;";

}
```

The `$curlCookies` var now looks like this :

```
NID=somelooooooooooongvalue;SID=somelooooooooooooooongvalue;
```

Now we can make the curl request using the `$curlCookies` inside the `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER`:

```
$url =  "https://some.host.com/that-need-selenium-cookies";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
"Host: some.host.com:443",
"Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8",
"Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8",
"Cookie: $curlCookies"
));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 120);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "");
$pagebody=curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
```

That's it, the code works perfectly.
I hope this helps others.